# Why does a frame keep a non null size when emptied?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a list of tasks to do. That list has several subgroups, that I want to display together. To do so I created a frame for each subgroup and display each tasks in the corresponding frame with grid(). Once a task is done, I destroy the corresponding label.

When a subgroup is empty from the start, tkinter reduce the size of the frame to 0, and I don't see it. But when a subgroup that had tasks becomes empty it seems to have a minimum size and does not disappear. Is there a way to prevent that?

Here is an example of my problem: the frame0 does not appear because it is empty (which is good). But even after destroying the labels of frame1 (with the buttons) the frame1 keeps one row for some reason.

```
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()

frame0=tk.Frame(window,bg='green')
frame1=tk.Frame(window,bg='red')
frame2=tk.Frame(window,bg='blue')
window.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

frame0.grid(sticky='ew')
frame1.grid(sticky='ew')
frame2.grid(sticky='ew')

labelList1=[]
for i in range(2):
    labelList1.append(tk.Label(frame1,text='Task type 1'))
    labelList1[-1].grid(sticky='ew',pady=5)

tk.Label(frame2,text='Task type 2: 1').grid(sticky='ew',pady=5)
tk.Label(frame2,text='Task type 2: 2').grid(sticky='ew',pady=5)

for i in range(2):
    tk.Button(window,text='Destroy {}'.format(i),command=labelList1[i].destroy).grid()

window.mainloop()
```

I have found a way around it by using only one frame and using rows 1 to 100 for subgroup 0, 101 to 200 to subgroup 1, etc But I don't find this elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter will not resize a Frame if it contains no child widgets. So if you had a callback that removed all your labels at once the Frame wouldn't resize at all. A simple (if somewhat kludgy) workaround is to add a dummy Frame widget to `frame1`. Eg, add this line

```
tk.Frame(frame1).grid()
```

before your `labelList1` loop.

---

FWIW, here's a variation of your code that destroys both the label and the corresponding button.

```
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()

frame0=tk.Frame(window,bg='green')
frame1=tk.Frame(window,bg='red')
frame2=tk.Frame(window,bg='blue')
window.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

frame0.grid(sticky='ew')
frame1.grid(sticky='ew')
frame2.grid(sticky='ew')

tk.Frame(frame1).grid()

num_tasks = 3
labelList1=[]
for i in range(num_tasks):
    labelList1.append(tk.Label(frame1,text='Task type 1: {}'.format(i)))
    labelList1[-1].grid(sticky='ew',pady=5)

tk.Label(frame2,text='Task type 2: 1').grid(sticky='ew',pady=5)
tk.Label(frame2,text='Task type 2: 2').grid(sticky='ew',pady=5)

def kill_label_and_button(l, b):
    l.destroy()
    b.destroy()

for i in range(num_tasks):
    b = tk.Button(window,text='Destroy {}'.format(i))
    b.config(command=lambda l=labelList1[i], b=b: kill_label_and_button(l, b))
    b.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nice trick with the lambda function. I had never seen default parameters in lambda function. I was using partial() instead.

Comment: @Florent: It's a pretty standard trick, and it's more efficient than using `partial`. It works because default values for args are set when the function is created (whether it's a `def` or a  `lambda`).